# Creating Python 3.6 AWS Lambda package

Tags: aws-lambda, python-3.6

My OS is win 10 Home. 
I have a Python 3.6 script that updates an MSSql DB, using pymssql. The script works fine locally.
Now I need to upload it as aws lambda, so I followed this using the cmd:

```
python -m venv .
Scripts\activate
pip install pymssql
```

Then I copied my py function to the Lib\site-packages dir, ziped all the dir content and uploaded it to the Lambda service.

The result was this error:

```
Unable to import module 'validationLambda': No module named 'pymssql'
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What is your functions handler method?

Answer (score 1):

I am not strong with Windows environments but you should probably try to do the opposite.
Copy the `Lib\site-packages\pymssql` directory to the root of your package (same level with `your_function.py`

Answer (score 0):

Try to `import cython` along with `pymssql`.